# Добавить объект в UITabBar-панель

Tags: objective-c, ios7

Допустим, есть у меня табы, на которых расположены UICollectionView с рисунками. Есть желание добавить в панель таббара иконку (объект) корзины, на которую юзер будет перетягивать и дропать элемент коллекции (т.е. рисунок).

Возможно ли добавить объект другого типа (будь то кнопка или лэйбл) в панельку как элемент таббара, но при этом чтобы он совершал совсем другое действие, а не открывал контроллер?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TabBarItem смотрите